# What's the algorithm for checking for a valid solution to a rectangular sliding tile puzzle like the fifteen puzzle?

Tags: algorithm

I can easily look up the algorithm for a regular, square shaped puzzle (such as 4x4), but I don't know if the algorithm for a rectangular puzzle exists (such as 3x5 or 6x2). I want to think it's just the same as the fifteen puzzle by just multiplying N*M for length and width respectively, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Why the downvote? Seems OK to me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the question is about rectangular puzzles (such as 5x3), not square puzzles (4x4) with rectangular tiles:

An inversion is a pair of tiles that are in the reverse order from where they ought to be. The polarity of a puzzle is whether the total number of inversions among all tiles is even or odd. A puzzle with 10 inversions has even polarity; a puzzle with 7 inversions has odd polarity.

The solved puzzle has zero inversions (and even polarity) by definition. Every 
`enter code here`puzzle of any size with even polarity is solvable. For some puzzle sizes, all puzzles are solvable.

You can find the maths on Wikipedia or Wolfram: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/15Puzzle.html.